# How to compile static racket binaries

Tags: compilation, lisp, racket, static-compilation

`raco exe` makes dynamic executables, and `raco distribute` doesn't change that:

```
$ ldd ./tst                            
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc9ed46000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fbeb4c09000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbeb4a18000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbeb4c67000)
```

On windows, it looks like one can `--embed-dlls`, which is kindof what I want, but for all platforms.

**I'd like to compile statically for ease of distribution and deployment. Is this possible?**

Comment: Do operating systems even support static linking any more?  I'm both impressed and depressed that they do.

Comment: Heh! You've blinked and missed the static revolution that Go and Rust have started! I've got a taste of deploying a single binary into a container AND I WANT MORE!

Comment: To be fair, it's easy to statically compile Haskell too

Comment: So, when you statically link your application with that version of the SSL libraries with all the security vulnerabilities & then deploy it on a platform where those vulnerabilities are fixed, except, oops, they're not because the static binary just shipped them back in again: that's going to work out well, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, and visa versa - my deployed app doesn't inherit YOUR old versions security flaws :-P

Comment: I see what you're saying - it's your machine, you are responsible for it. The solution is to recompile, which is easy to do.

Comment: I think you're imagining apps on a desktop os, where the user upgrades the system regularly. I'm imagining a single binary app deployed onto a container on aws that will only be updated with a new deploy.